# Un-register gitlab-runner on Ubuntu not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitlab-ci, ubuntu-18.04, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to unregister gitlab-runner on EC2 instance (Ubuntu machine) with the following command:

```
sudo gitlab-runner --debug unregister --token [RUNNER-TOKEN] --url [RUNNER-URL]
```

and I'm getting following error:

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=2374 revision=6fbc7474 version=13.1.1
Checking runtime mode                               GOOS=linux uid=0
Running in system-mode.

Dialing: tcp gitlab.com:443 ...
ERROR: Unregistering runner from GitLab forbidden   runner=xv2Ng6Tc
FATAL: Failed to unregister runner
```

Answer (score 39):

Make sure that you're using the entire SHA, not the partial one listed on the Gitlab CI runners list.

This can be found by running `sudo gitlab-runner list` on the machine with the runner installed.

If you've already removed the runner in the gitlab runners page, it will still be present on the gitlab-runner machine (check with the command `sudo gitlab-runner list`).

You can then unregister it from the config.toml using the command:

```sh
gitlab-runner verify --delete
```

Or manually, by running:

- `sudo gitlab-runner stop`
- `sudo vi /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` # update the runners section
- `sudo gitlab-runner start`

Comment: Btw, this should be the answer!

Comment: gitlab-runner verify --delete will not work if the gitlab url does not longer exists, but manually remove works like a charm.

Comment: After remove from gitlab project page this command is enough for me "gitlab-runner verify --delete"

Answer (score 23):

**For MacOS and Ubuntu**

**If you have already removed it from the Runners section in your project settings** then you are no longer be able to unregister with command. Then what you can do is to delete them from your host as below:

```
gitlab-runner verify --delete
```

This will remove all the unregistered/removed runners from your host machine and will update `config.toml` file.

---

**If you haven't removed it from Runners section in your project settings**(**`Settings -> CI/CD -> Runners`**), then you can unregister it from your host like below:

```
gitlab-runner unregister runner_id/name
```

or unregister all runners,

```
gitlab-runner unregister --all-runners
```

Hope this will help to somebody. cheers !!!

Comment: I had configured a runner for a project. Then decided I wanted a shared runner, and removed it from the project and set up a runner _with the same name_. When I wanted to reconfigure the latter runner, I couldn't unregister it _by name_ (`-n`) until I used the `gitlab-runner verify --delete` command to clear out the original.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same issue when I tried to remove a runner that was removed directly from Gitlab settings of the project.
It seems that "Remove runner"'s button removes the runner from Gitlab but not from your gitlab-runner, which is absolutely fine since I don't want Gitlab to mess up to my on-premise gitlab-runner.

[image: Cursed button here]

In order to fix that, I stopped the gitlab-runner service, removed the runner directly from the config file (it is usually located in /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml) and started the service again.

I hope I could help you ;)

Comment: `gitlab-runner verify --delete` would have done that without editing a config file

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still struggling with this like me, then here is something from docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#gitlab-runner-unregister

`gitlab-runner unregister --url http://gitlab.example.com/ --token <full_token_from_etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml>`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I had to enter the right token in the config.toml file and boom, it worked: See this [guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4919) for more information: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4919. This solution is specifically for Windows, but can be applicable to Ubuntu as well.